# Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\default.ctp [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 425]

Tags: cakephp

help me to show my own message.
I'm using

```
    $this->Session->setFlash(_('My Custom message Here'));
```

I have tried lots of things but unable to overcome from this error.

Comment: paste the code of your default.ctp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a file named `default.ctp` in `View/Elements` folder

Write the following code in that file

```
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

and write the following code where you want to show the message

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

Comment: How to accept as an answer..? I don't know. I'm new here.

Comment: @amarpremcool You will see an arrow (✓) at upper left side under the votes of my answer. Click on that and its done. It will be green after accepting.

Comment: i do it. Thanks Once again for your answer.